# Use TikZ foreach variable in node

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

This MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis
, xmin=2, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=12, clip=false, axis y line*=right]
    \foreach \blah in {0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{
        \addplot[mark=none, domain=2:10, thick] {-ln(\blah/x^2)/ln(x)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=$}; %Varying c_2 values
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces this result

[image: Graph showing unlabeled c_2 values]

Note that the `c_2=` nodes on the left-hand side have no values on by the equal sign. I thought I could fix that by using

```
\addplot[mark=none, domain=2:10, thick] {-ln(\blah/x^2)/ln(x)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=$\blah}; %Varying c_2 values
```

But this doesn't work because PDFLaTeX tells me that I have an "Undefined control sequence." while referring to `\blah`.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PGFPlots includes a special looping mechanism that avoids problems with unexpanded macros:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{<list>}{
    < code where the list element is available as #1 >
}
```

In your case, you would write

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{
        \addplot[mark=none, domain=2:10, thick] {-ln(#1/x^2)/ln(x)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=#1$}; 
}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Elegant, thanks, Jake! This is the last of three questions I've posted today. You've been a great resource on all of them.

Answer (score 6):

You can force `\blah` to be expanded before it goes out of scope:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\def\doit#1{%
 \addplot[mark=none, domain=2:10, thick] {-ln(#1/x^2)/ln(x)} node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=#1$}; %Varying c_2 values
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
    \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis, xlabel=X-Axis
, xmin=2, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=12, clip=false, axis y line*=right]
    \foreach \blah in {0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{
     \expandafter\doit\expandafter{\blah}       
    }
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked well, but it seems complex... is there no "simpler" solution?

Comment: Well apparently yes see @Jake s answer, but he has an advantage over me of having used tikz before:-) Complexity is in the eye of the beholder...

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why a direct expansion isn't used in this case. We see the syntax and what needs protection.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
  \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis,xlabel=X-Axis,xmin=2,
  xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=12,clip=false,axis y line*=right]
  \foreach\x in {0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{%
    \edef\x{\noexpand\addplot[mark=none,domain=2:10,thick]
      {-ln(\x/x^2)/ln(x)}node[pos=0,left] {$c_2=\x$}}\x;
  }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

**EDIT** 2012/7/19

**1.** The problem Marc van Dongen has reported in his comment applies on my machine also to Jake's solution:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
  \begin{axis}[ylabel=Y-Axis,xlabel=X-Axis,xmin=2,xmax=10,ymin=0,
    ymax=12, clip=false, axis y line*=right]
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0.9,0.5,0.2,0.1,0.05,0.02,0.01,0.005}{%
      \addplot[mark=none,domain=2:10,thick]{-ln(#1/x^2)/ln(x)}
        node [pos=0,left] {$c_2=#1$};
    }%
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe I have messed something up. I will allow Jake to confirm or disprove of this before posting a working example.

[image]

**2.** (Re)defining `\x` within a tikzpicture environment is harmless, provided the user knows what he is doing. `\x` isn't defined by TikZ itself.

Here is an example that works on my machine:

```
\begin{document}
% Style 1:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \foreach \am in {1,2,3}{%
    \addplot{x^\am};
    \addlegendentryexpanded{$x^\am$}
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Style 2:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \foreach \x in {1,2,3}{%
    \edef\x{%
      \noexpand\addplot{x^\x};
      \noexpand\addlegendentry{$x^\x$}
    }\x
  }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The labels (`$c_2=\x$`) for the graphs all end up at the bottom. Also, I'm worried about redefining `\x` in a `tikzpicture`.

Comment: Both code chunks work fine for me. Note that the `node [pos=...]` feature was only introduced in a relatively recent version of PGFPlots (1.5, I think), so maybe you're using an older version.

Comment: Redefining `\x` is not harmless, even if the user knows what they're doing. The reason for this is that `\x` is a `tikz` primitive, which may be used by `pgfplots`. When implementation of `tikz` or `pgfplots` changes, code that worked before the change may not work after the change.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: Please see my question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64065/is-x-a-primitive-anywhere.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'd be surprised if it were: the TikZ/PGF manual is full of `\foreach\x`. Skimming through `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots` I find only similar uses of `\x` and no definition whatsoever. The same in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf`

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Just back from two days in Kerry. My reference to _redefining_ `\x` wasn't correct. Still I don't think it's clever to rely on a globally defined macro `\x` in Tikz/`pgfplots`. E.g when `pgfplots` displays the label that typesets the `\x`, it may redefine `\x` in a `let`. For example, the following will not work: '\def\x{a}\tikz\draw let \p{a}=(1,1) in (\x{a},0) node {\x};`. (This is all I meant.)