# Is \x a primitive anywhere?

Tags: tikz-pgf

It is claimed by Marc van Dongen at [Use TikZ foreach variable in node](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63817/use-tikz-foreach-variable-in-node) that `\x` is a "TiKZ primitive". Does TikZ have primitives? I can't understand why on earth any package would make `\x` a primitive, and I assume that outside TeX engines/platforms only LuaTeX can make a package/user command equivalent to a primitive. Please can anyone tell me the meaning of the `\x` primitive? I can't see it defined outside or within `tikzpicture`!

**EDIT**

I have now seen what is going on. Although TikZ has no primitives, Marc van Dongen has a point. From cjorssen's example,

```
\draw plot[samples=10,domain=-5:5] (\y,{(\y)^2})
```

fails, while

```
\draw plot[variable=\y,samples=10,domain=-5:5] (\y,{(\y)^2})
```

works. In my humble opinion, PGF shouldn't have used a generic macro like `\x` as a default scratch macro, even in a local group or with a restored stack. It may be convenient for users, but, as we've seen, it is not the best choice of a scratch variable.

Comment: As far as I know it's used simply as a scratch macro like `\next`.

Comment: "Primitive" just isn't the word that should be used in this context (as you explained yourself).

Comment: You can do `\draw[domain=-1:1] plot (\x, {exp(\x)});` in `tikz`.

Comment: @canaaerus This doesn't mean that `\x` has a constant definition outside that context. If you add `\show\x;`, the answer will be `\x=undefined`.

Comment: I was not careful when I wrote _redefining_ `\x`. In my more recent comment I clarify my comment why it is not clever to rely on a globally defined `\x` in tikz/`pgfplots`. The reason is that they may redefine `\x` as part of a `let` operation. I also give an example. Hope this clarifies my comment. I still believe using `\x` in your example is flawed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\x` is not a tikz "primitive" as far as I understand. It can be used in the `plot` operation but it is behind the scenes used by `\foreach`. See in the following example: the two `\draw` commands do more or less the same (see lines 388- in `pgfmoduleplot.code.tex` and lines 2899- in `tikz.code.tex`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw plot[samples=10,domain=-5:5] (\x,{(\x)^2});
  \draw[red] (-5,{(-5)^2}) \foreach \x in {-4,...,5} {-- (\x,{(\x)^2})};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `\foreach` variable (here `\x`) is group protected so the fact that `\x` would be defined elsewhere is not a problem here.

I'd say that even if the implementation of the `plot` operation change in the future, tikz/pgf developers would take care of protecting the definition of `\x`.

Comment: I'd say that in the `\draw plot` example `\x` is simply part of the syntax and has no real meaning by itself. In `pgfmoduleplot.code.tex` there's no `\x` other than in the example on line 384, where `\x` can be changed into `\foo`, if one wants. In `tikz.code.tex` there's `\def\tikz@plot@var{\x}` which doesn't imply that `\x` has a definition.

Comment: @egreg Yes `\x` can be undefined or not, it does not matter for tikz/pgf. But if it is defined, tikz will redefined it internally and then restore its original definition. It is a dummy "variable" (that can be changed with `variable` option BTW).

Comment: @AhmedMusa The meaning of `\x` is changed only locally anyway in `\draw plot`. I don't see why it shouldn't be used: if you are in the middle of a `\foreach\x` you know you are and will use `variable=\y`.

Comment: @egreg: My point is that if they did that with `\x`, it becomes difficult to predict what else they did with `\x` in the behemoth called PGF. I hope they will one day use something specific to PGF, like `\pgftemp`.

Comment: @AhmedMusa `ack '\\x[^a-z]' /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/`